# intro js is not worked when checking Cookies

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, intro.js

i want to create INTRO js to my website, when user first time visit my website.
I use cookies with PHP. but its not worked.

This is my code

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["userip"]))
        {
            echo " $_COOKIE[userip]";
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <script>
            //I THINK THE PROBLEM IS AT THIS JS LINE
           // introJs();
            //javascript:introJs.start();
            introJs().setOption('showProgress', true).start();
            </script>
            <?php
            setcookie("userip", "mycookiename", time()+3600);
        }


<script type="text/javascript" src="intro.js"></script>
```

but if i put:

`introJs().setOption('showProgress', true).start();`

in body onload it is work.
but what i need is checking cookies first.

pls help me

thank you

Comment: Can you post the full php script properly

Comment: i think my problem not in PHP script, but how to call introJs() properly inside javascript. introJs();  OR javascript:introJs.start(); OR introJs().setOption('showProgress', true).start();....Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem is now fixed,
i change javascript code like be like this:

```
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          javascript:introJs().setOption('showProgress', true).start();
        });
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is resolved by changing the order of scripts (or maybe adding a close tag to your first):

```
<!-- load intro.js FIRST -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="intro.js"></script>
<!-- use intro.js -->
<script>
  // include any options you want
  introJs().start();

  // set cookies if you want 
  // ...
</script>
```